# Setting a database login password without setting the connection string

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, passwords, connection-string, database-backups

I've taken over a vb.net project, and one feature of it is that it automatically creates a daily database backup when the system is first opened each day.

One thing the client has asked for, is for me to put a password on the database, to make it more secure, and restrict access to it, as he will be selling on the project further.

I've added a password, and set the password in the connection string to log into the program, however I need to set the password for the backup to happen, but at the moment, I can't work out where the password would go, since I've never done anything similar to this before (as I'm only an apprentice at the moment).

What is the easiest way to set a password for the backup? This is the code that currently takes care of it

```
 If .Item("autoBackup") = True Then
                    If .Item("buDaily") = True Then

                        sql = "SELECT * FROM [System Settings]"
                        dataAd = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
                        dataset = New DataSet
                        dataAd.Fill(dataset)

                        With dataset.Tables(0).Rows(0)
                            If File.Exists(.Item("backupPath") & "backup" & _
                            DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM") & ".mdb") = True Then
                            Else

                                System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf asyncBackupDaily)

                            End If
                        End With
                    End If
```

**EDIT**

This is the code for `asyncBackupDaily`

```
Private Sub asyncBackupDaily(ByVal state As Object)

    Try
        sql = "SELECT * FROM [System Settings]"
        dataAd = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        dataSet = New DataSet
        dataAd.Fill(dataSet)

        Dim currentDB As String = readIni("DATABASE", directorypath & "settings.ini")
        Dim newDB As String = dataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("backupPath") & _
        "backup" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM") & ".mdb"

        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(currentDB, dataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("backupPath") & _
      "backup" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM") & "-nc.mdb", True)

        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(newDB) = True Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(newDB)
        End If

        Dim dbo As New DAO.DBEngine
        dbo.CompactDatabase(dataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("backupPath") & _
        "backup" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM") & "-nc.mdb", newDB & ";pwd=Acplus2016!")

        Try
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(dataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("backupPath") & _
       "backup" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM") & "-nc.mdb")

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

        MsgBox("Daily auto-backup successful!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Success")

    Catch ex As Exception
        errorLog(ex)

    End Try
End Sub
```

Error is on line `dbo.CompactDatabase(dataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("backupPath") & "backup" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM") & "-nc.mdb", newDB)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix to this;

The error, on line `dbo.CompactDatabase` was because of the parameters. "The password is not valid"

Solve was to change this line to the following

```
dbo.CompactDatabase(dataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("backupPath") & "backup" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM") & "-nc.mdb", newDB, Nothing, Nothing, ";pwd=myPassword")
```